# Spring getOne(id) issue - existing id's coming up null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am using a newer version of Spring-boot in my project, so instead of using the findById(Long id), I am using getOne(Long id) (the Optional findById wasn't working for me). My "save new form" method works fine, and the SQL database creates an id for the submitted form (aka broker). But when editing the form I can not access the existing id and am getting a null error. Could someone please point me in the right direction here. Is it because I am using getOne method that this is coming back null, or is there something else going on causing this issue?

Here is the trace stack to show the 500 Error for having a null ID.

```
2019-03-08 14:58:32.416 DEBUG 988 --- [p-nio-64-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={masked}
2019-03-08 14:58:32.417 DEBUG 988 --- [p-nio-64-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2019-03-08 14:58:32.418 DEBUG 988 --- [p-nio-64-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-03-08 14:58:32.418 DEBUG 988 --- [p-nio-64-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Fri Mar 08 14:58:32 PST 2019, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, message=The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!, path=/saveBroker}]
2019-03-08 14:58:32.419 DEBUG 988 --- [p-nio-64-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500
```

Here are my controller functions:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/newBroker")
    public String newBroker(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("broker",new Broker());
        return "brokerProfile";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addBroker")
    public String addBroker(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value="broker") Broker broker)
    {
        Long id=null;
        try{
            Broker newBroker = brokerRepository.save(broker);
            id = newBroker.getId();
            if (broker.getStatus().equals("active"))
                broker.setOnboardedDate(LocalDate.now());
            brokerRepository.save(newBroker);
        }catch (DataAccessException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "redirect:/edit/"+id;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}")
    public String editbroker(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long id, Broker broker){
        Broker existing= brokerRepository.getOne(id);
        model.addAttribute("broker",existing);
        return "brokerProfile";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/saveBroker")
    @ResponseBody
    public JSONObject saveBroker(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value="broker") Broker broker)
    {
        Boolean saved=false;
        JSONObject response=new JSONObject();
        Broker brokerBeforeUpdate = brokerRepository.getOne(broker.getId());

        if (brokerBeforeUpdate!=null && !brokerBeforeUpdate.getStatus().equals("active") && broker.getStatus().equals("active"))
            broker.setOnboardedDate(LocalDate.now());
        else if (!broker.getStatus().equals("active"))
            broker.setOnboardedDate(null);
            try{
                brokerBeforeUpdate=brokerRepository.save(broker);
                saved=true;
                response.put("brokerId",broker.getId());

            }catch (DataAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response.put("error",e.getLocalizedMessage());
                response.put("cause",e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        response.put("success",saved);
        return response;
    }
}
```

My Repository pretaining to getOne()/findById

```
public interface BrokerRepository extends CrudRepository<Broker,Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

    Broker save(Broker entity);

//    <Optional>Broker findById(Long id);

    Broker getOne(Long id);


    void delete(Broker entity);

    List<Broker> findAll();

}
```

Broker. java piece pertaining to ID

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Broker")
public class Broker {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "brokerId")
    private Long id;

        public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Comment: i don't see this method in `CrudRepository`https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html

Comment: @Deadpool if I use brokerRepository.findById(broker.getId());I get this error: Error:(61, 53) java: reference to findById is ambiguous
  both method findById(ID) in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository and method <Optional>findById(java.lang.Long) in com.project1.repositories.BrokerRepository match.       I found the getOne option in a stackoverflow question.

Comment: @Deadpool, I am not sure how to use Optionals. If I change it to <Optional>B findById(Long id), how am I supposed to call this in my functions? brokerRepository.findById( ---what goes in here??---) ?

Comment: `brokerRepository.findById( ---what goes in here??---)` id goes there `brokerRepository.findById( id)`

Comment: @Deadpool  It doesn't work though because I get Error: java: reference to findById is ambiguous both method findById(ID) org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository and method <Optional>findById(java.lang.Long) in com.Portal.repositories.BrokerRepository match

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the method used in the @RequestMethod because it has no default value

```
@RequestMapping(path="/",method=RequestMethod.GET or POST)
```

but you use this instead of @RequestMethod

```
@PostMethod(path='/')
@GetMethod(path='/')
```

Comment: GET is default for @RequestMapping

Comment: I'm not sure that the @requestMapping is the issue since it does post new brokers. If I specify the Post of Get method, I will have to repeat the code in the method so it works for both otherwise I get a 405 error. Is there not a way to get the method to work when finding the id?